# Hazelcast cluster issue

Tags: java, spring, quarkus, hazelcast, ovh

I have java application with hazelcast client. Application being running on 2 different server. First time when on both server the application start they form a cluster but as I put down one of the node and bring it up, it takes around "5 min" to form a cluster, till then the node I brought up running as a standalone instance. I am not sure why is this happenning ?

I have Tcpipconfig enable with list of 2 members. I am using embedded hazelcast

Comment: Does it do this with the latest version ? (Which today is 5.3.5)

Comment: If that doesn't work, logs will be helpful